# Calculating EER from FAR and FRR with upper and lower bounds

Tags: classification, threshold

Excuse me if this question is not correct, I am not very familiar with the field.

I am trying to calculate EER based on FAR and FRR, when having both upper and lower bounds (`max_threshold`, `min_threshold`). I have not come across anything similar yet, but my thinking is the following:

I have classified values as genuine (1) and not genuine (0). I then set the upper bound to be the highest acceptable value. I calculate the EER when the upper bound is equal to the `max_threshold` and the lower bound changes. I store that in a table. I then set the upper bound to be `max_threshold - 1` and repeat the process. I keep reducing the upper bound, until it meets the lower bound. I finally pick the best performing EER.

I have two questions:

1. Is this the correct way of doing it? If not, is there a standard way of doing it?
2. After doing it, my graph looks like the following. As I said, I am not very familiar with the field, but it is my understanding that FAR and FRR should start at 100% and 0%, respectively. Using this method it seems that they do not. If this method is correct, how would I interpret this?

[image: FAR/FRR curves]